# loading hiding not working after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with loading Gif with #loading Id,
I wrote java script for hiding that on window loading:

```
<div id="loading">
  <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading..."/>
</div>
```

...

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#loading').hide();
});
```

It works on form loading, I create a form to going to other page:

```
     function gotopage(destpage){
        var form = document.createElement("form");

        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("action", "index.php");
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'hidden';
                input.name = 'page';
                input.value = destpage;
                form.appendChild(input);
        document.body.appendChild(form);        
        form.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(form);      
     }
```

when I go to other page with this form, hiding not work correctly and loading not hide.

do you have any solution?

Comment: first thing, why would you navigate to new page using this method? is it so the `index.php` will redirect the user to another URL, or `index.php` will render the page content depending on `page: destpage` while maintaining the same URL (eg: http://xxx/index.php)

Comment: can you please send me complete code?

Comment: index redirects the user to itself while destpage is a subpage of index using include in php, the reason is that user see just "index" in address bar